# Imprimindo lixo de memória do vetor

Tags: c, array, memória

Como faço para que um programa não imprima lixo de um vetor?

Por exemplo, criei 2 vetores no início do meu programa com 5 elementos cada. Se o usuário digitar números acima de 10 armazena em `v1` se for maior armazena em `v2`. Porém, quando imprimo, se o usuário não digitou nenhum número que atenda essas condições, o programa imprime lixo de memória.

Teria como imprimir somente os vetores que contenham valores?

Programa só para exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n 5

int main()
{   
    int v1[n], v2[n], a, i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      printf("Digite: ");
      scanf("%d",&a);
     if(a<=5) v1[i] = a;
      else v2[i] = a;
          }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        printf("%d ", v1[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        printf("%d ", v2[i]);
    }
 

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Tem um problema conceitual no armazenamento. E nem sei se dá para fazer certo porque o enunciado é ruim.

Cada vetor precisa armazenar apenas os números que são pertinentes a eles. Então cada posição do vetor avança conforme um item é colocado ali, portanto precisa contar quantos itens já foram colocados em cada um e esta contagem é posição que deve colocar. Assim não deixa buracos nos vetores e depois saberá quantos tem em cada para exibir apenas a quantidade que foi preenchida.

De forma mais organizada e legível:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5

int main() {   
    int menores[MAX], maiores[MAX], cont_menores = 0, cont_maiores = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Digite: ");
        int numero;
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        if (numero > 10) maiores[cont_maiores++] = numero;
        else menores[cont_menores++] = numero;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cont_menores; i++) printf("%d ", menores[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < cont_maiores; i++) printf("%d ", maiores[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0lVnnK). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/qqgtidmm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/IndependentIndex.c).

Comment: Na verdade estou fazendo um programa para ler as idades que o usuário digitar, e separar em 3 vetores, menor de idade, maior e idoso. Quando eu imprimo esses vetores, caso o usuário tenha digitado apenas idades maiores por exemplo, o programa imprime lixo de memória, dos outros dois vetores.

Comment: Eu respondi o que você perguntou.